# Using several languages in Sublime Text 3 spell check

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I have two dictionaries: ru_RU and en_US. How can I use it together in Sublime Text 3 spell check? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible. It has been mentioned in the official issues list for ST3 - see [this issue](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1069) for details.

Answer (score 3):

I have this working for me using this steps.

1. Download your dictionary (e.g. from GitHub or following the README.md recipe in this respository).
2. Create a folder in your Sublime Text 3 config (e.g. "Language - Spanish"), this will be the name shown in the ST menu, and move the dictionary inside this folder.

   ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Language - Spanish
3. Be sure that spell checking is active and the dictionaries as well in your preference settings:

   "spell_check": true,
   "dictionary": [
      "Packages/Language - English/en_US.dic", 
      "Packages/Language - Spanish/Spanish.dic"
   ],
4. Now you can switch the current spell checking:

View > Dictionary > Language - Spanish > Spanish

Comment: This array format for this setting worked for me, and I hope the documentation page points to that : [https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/spell_checking.html](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/spell_checking.html)

Answer (score 1):

For me was solved following this instructions:
https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/spell_checking.html

I've downloaded the `dict` files from:
https://github.com/SublimeText/Dictionaries

Then I simply copy the UTF-8 encoded dictionary files (in my case `Spanish`) into `Packages/Language - Spanish/` (You can access it from `Preferences/Browse Packages`).

Then activate by adding this line to user setting's

```
"spell_check": true,
```

Or by `View/Spell Check` menu.

You can select the dictionary from the `View/Dictionary` menu.

It would not be an easy task to create the affix for a "merged" language, like 2 dicts working at once. In my case I'd love some `Spanglish` dict... have to work on it.